# UV Reprojection help

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, uv

I have a mesh that is generated by another system that I do not have access to. I need to make game ready assets out of it and part of that job is to make LODs. I came across an issue where once the mesh is decimated I get texture bleed / texture distortion. I looked at the texture that comes with a mesh and it has thousands of small UV islands and a few large ones.

So, I decided to use Smart Project + Repack UVs + Bake to try to reUV this mesh. Generally speaking that works, but here and there I would see small black areas. I eventually figured out that those are caused by super tiny UV islands that were less than a pixel size during the bake process.

Another issue I ran into is that during smart project some UVs end up overlapping and it results with parts of a mesh texture imprinted on a adjacent areas (like couch imprinted on the floor and floor imprinted on the couch). I am not sure why repack UVs doesnt help with that. Only thing that helps is either making angle for smart project smaller or smooth vertices a lot (restore their position after).

Any ideas on how to improve this? I generally would like to create a UV map with less islands, so that i have less issues with LOD creation. This process has to be fully automated.

Maybe there is another way to create LODs without messing with UVs that doesnt cause texture bleed?

Original texture (each box is a separate UV island):
[image]

Full res couch:
[image]

Black triangles:
[image]

Imprint issues (overlapping UVs):
[image]

Note: I also struggled with creating an algorithm that would help me find UV islands. This is a single mesh, so my best approach was this:
1. make a list of all faces (some meshes have millions)
2. get uv for one of the loops in the face
3. do this for each uv bpy.ops.uv.select(location=uv)
4. then this bpy.ops.uv.select_linked()
5. grab selected faces (which would be an island)
6. remove selected faces from the list
7. go back to step 2
On some meshes this would take hours.
Is there a better way?

I know this is a lot, so thank you for even reading this. Thanks for any help!

Cheers!

Comment: Looks like a 3D scan. I'd suggest that you create a copy of the object, retopo for a clean topology, then create UV seams and do a proper UV unwrap and bake the original texture onto the clean mesh. That way you have a nice topology and a clean UV layout. Posting this as a comment, because it's not exactly full instructions.

Comment: Is retopo a blender process? if so, can you give me some pointers? And yeah, original mesh is from a 3D scan

Comment: You can do it Blender (use the snap feature and maybe the new poly build tool) or use a tool like InstantMeshes to automatically generate a new topology. (https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes)

Comment: that sounds interesting, i am going to give it a go. thanks!

Comment: InstantMesh produces pretty nice results, is it possible to bake onto the mesh produced with InstantMesh using original mesh as source (InstantMesh doesn't load textures unfortunately)

Comment: Yes of course that's what you generally do.